# Google Charts - Format number

Tags: numbers, format, google-visualization

Same code
http://jsbin.com/EFayoCI/1
[image]

Old chart
I want number format like that
[image]

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The formatter for the Visualization API cannot convert numbers into shorthand metrics (eg "5000" into "5k").  If you want that effect, you have two options:

1. specify the `vAxis.ticks` option to create custom labels for each axis value

   ```
   vAxis: {
       ticks: [{v: 1500000, f: '1500k'}, {v: 1570000, f: '1570k'}, {v: 1640000, f: '1640k'}, {v: 1710000, f: '1710k'}, {v: 1780000, f: '1780k'}]
   }
   ```
2. use a DataView to reduce the size of the data passed to the chart

   ```
   var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
   view.setColumns([0, {
       type: 'number',
       label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
       calc: function (dt, row) {
           return {v: dt.getValue(row, 1) / 1000, f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1)};
       }
   }]);
   chart.draw(view, {
       vAxis: {
           format: '#k'
       }
   });
   ```

**[edit: here's a full example chart that formats the axis and data in B, KB, MB, GB, as appropriate]**

```
function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'File Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'File Size');
    data.addRows([
        ['foo.exe', 45000000],
        ['bar.zip', 600000000],
        ['baz.iso', 1700000000]
    ]);

    // custom format data values
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top);
            // sometimes, the axis value falls 1/2 way though the pixel height of the gridline,
            // so we need to add in 1/2 the height
            // this assumes that all axis values will be integers
            if (val != parseInt(val)) {
                val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top + bb.height / 2);
            }

            // convert from base-10 counting to 2^10 counting
            for (var n = 0; val >= 1000; n++) {
                val /= 1000;
            }
            formattedVal = val;
            val *= Math.pow(1024, n);

            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    suffix = 'B';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    suffix = 'KB';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suffix = 'MB';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suffix = 'GB';
                    break;
                default:
                    // format to GB
                    while (n > 3) {
                        formattedVal *= 1024;
                        n--;
                    }
                    suffix = 'GB'
            }

            ticks.push({v: val, f: formattedVal + suffix});
    }

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var options = {
        height: 400,
        width: 600
    };

    // get the axis values and reformat them
    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        var bb, val, suffix, ticks = [], cli = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
        for (var i = 0; bb = cli.getBoundingBox('vAxis#0#gridline#' + i); i++) {
            val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top);
            // sometimes, the axis value falls 1/2 way though the pixel height of the gridline,
            // so we need to add in 1/2 the height
            // this assumes that all axis values will be integers
            if (val != parseInt(val)) {
                val = cli.getVAxisValue(bb.top + bb.height / 2);
            }
            // using 1000 here to keep the axis neat
            // this messes a bit with the scale of the chart, so you might want to change it
            for (var n = 0, formattedVal = val; formattedVal >= 1000; n++) {
                formattedVal /= 1000;
            }
            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    suffix = 'B';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    suffix = 'KB';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    suffix = 'MB';
                    break;
                case 3:
                    suffix = 'GB';
                    break;
                default:
                    // format to GB
                    while (n > 3) {
                        formattedVal *= 1000;
                        n--;
                    }
                    suffix = 'GB'
            }
            ticks.push({v: val, f: formattedVal + suffix});
        }
        options.vAxis = options.vAxis || {};
        options.vAxis.ticks = ticks;
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/M58Wt/

Comment: Thanks for solution,And other question, if a big data from column 1 and i want convert format from 5000000 to 5M or other format for big data,Can you help me ?

Comment: You can do the same thing with millions - just divide by 1000000 instead of 1000.  If you want to split between different scales (eg, have axis values "800k", "900k", "1M", "1.1M"), you have to use the first method (setting `vAxis.ticks`).

Comment: I want format in column like Format bytes to kilobytes (K), megabytes(M), gigabytes (G) and Do display this format to vAxis?

Answer (score 2):

Google now supports large numbers formatting for axis labels: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats

option: `vAxis: {format: 'short'}`

http://output.jsbin.com/liteqozore/1